Why is my conditional inference tree so different from my random forest?
I am analyzing a data set using conditional inference trees and random forests, using the R package partykit (v. 1.2.20). For my dependent variable (likelihood of responding), the tree and the forest yield really different solutions, which makes either of them difficult to interpret. How can I understand what is going on here?
Below are my code and images of the tree and the forest. I can share the data set if necessary.
set.seed(2356)
library(partykit)

> head(s1_images_response_item[,-2])
# A tibble: 6 × 14
# Groups:   item [6]
  item     category   response_mean_img causation colorful familiarity  grow intention
  <chr>    <chr>                  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 airplane moving-ar…             1          3.25     2.57        4.4   1         1.29
2 algae    plant-fun…             0.887      2.44     3.57        2.1   4.14      1.06
3 antelope animal                 0.981      4.25     2.79        3.85  4.77      3.53
4 bicycle  moving-ar…             1          2.12     2.64        4.65  1.05      1.12
5 boat     moving-ar…             0.981      3.19     2.64        3.65  1         1   
6 boulder  nonmoving…             0.943      1.88     1.5         3     1.45      1.18
# ℹ 6 more variables: interaction <dbl>, movement <dbl>, natural <dbl>,
#   perception <dbl>, reproduce <dbl>, cue <chr>

Conditional inference tree:
tree1.i.h <- ctree(response_mean_img ~ causation + intention + 
    interaction + movement + perception + familiarity + natural + 
    grow + reproduce + colorful, data=s1_images_response_item)

plot(tree1.i.h, terminal_panel = node_boxplot(tree1.i.h,id=T),
     inner_panel = node_inner(tree1.i.h,id=F, pval = F), 
     edge_panel = edge_simple(tree1.i.h, digits = 2))

--> Familiarity is the only significant predictor:

Random forest:
f1.i.h <- cforest(response_mean_img ~ causation + intention + 
    interaction + movement + perception + familiarity + natural + 
    grow + reproduce + colorful, data=s1_images_response_item, 
    ntree = 1000)

f1.i.h.varimp <- varimp(f1.i.h)

dotchart(sort(f1.i.h.varimp,decreasing = F), 
    main = "Conditional importance of variables for Study 1B trial responsiveness")

--> The predictors interaction, reproduce, perception and causation all have higher conditional importance values than familiarity does:

Why aren't any of interaction, reproduce, perception and causation showing up in the tree?

In general, trees and forests use different strategies for avoiding overfitting. Individual trees are typically "pruned" so that they don't grow too large and don't overfit. In contrasts, random forests typically grow large unpruned trees and avoid overfitting by averaging over the trees.
The ctree() you by default uses a pre-pruning strategy and only proceeds to split the tree as long as there are splitting variables with a significant association with the dependent variable. In the root node "familiarity" is selected for splitting and in the left child node the sample size is too small. In the right child node, presumably the other potential splitting variables are not significant anymore.
The cforest() by default grows larger trees where the potential splitting variables are selected randomly via mtry. That's why generally the trees will use different splitting variables and some of these might turn out to work a little bit better than those selected by the default ctree().

Thank you for your comments. I am still trying to understand why, if "interaction" does so well when cforest is randomly selecting splitting variables, why isn't it the most associated splitting variable according to ctree?

I am also puzzling through how to present these conflicting results in a journal article. So far I have only seen published examples where the forest and tree align pretty well. If anyone can share a citation of a published manuscript where this type of discrepancy has been discussed, I would be appreciative.

First, if trees and forests would always be more or less in sync, we wouldn't need both methods. Second, it's hard to say why you only get a stump with the tree on the original data set, this is something you should investigate more. Given the moderate sample size it's not surprising that something like this can occur, but I wouldn't be surprised if this tree isn't particularly stable. See, for example, the stablelearner package and its stabletree() function for exploring the stability. Third, variable importances also have can have their problems and not provide the best overview.
